# UWP OnBackgroundActivated, no suitable method found to overrride

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to use the new 'Background activity with the Single Process Model' APIs to support my app with background task. But, I'm getting, 'no suitable method found to override' on the 'OnBackgroundActivated' method. What is wrong with my code?

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.EnteredBackground += Current_EnteredBackground;
    }

    private async void Current_EnteredBackground(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.EnteredBackgroundEventArgs e)
    {
        await RegisterBackgroundTask();
    }

    protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // show a toast
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async Task RegisterBackgroundTask()
    {
        BackgroundAccessStatus backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy ||
            backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed)
        {
            foreach (var bgTask in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (bgTask.Value.Name == "MyTask")
                {
                    bgTask.Value.Unregister(true);
                }
            }

            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            builder.Name = "MyTask";
            builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));

            // use builder.TaskEntryPoint if you want to not use the default OnBackgroundActivated
            // we’ll register it and now will start work based on the trigger, here we used a Time Trigger
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to override `OnBackgroundActivated` method in `MainPage` class. `MainPage` class is derived from [Page Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx), but [Application.OnBackgroundActivated method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onbackgroundactivated.aspx) is a method of [Application class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.aspx) which is not existed in `Page` Class, so you got the `no suitable method found to override` error.

To fix this issue, we need to put `OnBackgroundActivated` method in `App` class like:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Override the Application.OnBackgroundActivated method to handle background activation in 
    /// the main process. This entry point is used when BackgroundTaskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint is 
    /// not set during background task registration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

For more info about single process background task, please see [Support your app with background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) and [Background activity with the Single Process Model](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/07/background-activity-with-the-single-process-model/).

Comment: Thanks, it works. Never thought this way. I am very new to programming so it's a bit difficult to understand. Thanks!